# HTML/JavaScript/CSS: Change a picture by clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this question has been asked a bunch of times, and I looked at a few Topics on this site but I feel like my problem is a bit more specific.

So what my code currently does is if you click a plus button image shows text that is hidden underneath it. If you click the plus button image again the text hides itself again.

What I'm trying to do is when you show the hidden text, the plus button will turn into a minus button. If you hide the text again, the minus button will turn into a plus button.

In the code below, is one of the ways I tried by looking at previous questions.

I tried to name of the first image you can click as "img1". In the Javascript code under the "if(e.style.display=="block")" and "else" I wrote code that where I try to change the image of "img1" but nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

JSFiddle Link:
jsfiddle.net/YqDhe

Note that in JSFiddle the text appearing and disappearing does not work correctly but it does on the CMS I'm using.

```
<style>
    #para1, #para2, #para3{
        display:none;
    }
    .tab { 
        margin-left: 40px; 
        margin-right: 40px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">   
    function toggleMe(a){
        var e=document.getElementById(a);    
        if(!e){
            return false;
        }    
        if(e.style.display=="block"){
            e.style.display="none"
            e.getElementById("img1").src = "http://i.imgur.com/ZFvketc.png"
        }
        else{
            e.style.display="block"
            e.getElementById("img1").src = "http://i.imgur.com/lZIalfM.png"
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
<input type="image" name = "img1" src = "http://i.imgur.com/ZFvketc.png" onclick="return toggleMe('para1')" value="Toggle">
&nbsp; <font color="#0066a4">Who Am I</font><br>
<br>
<hr />
<p id="para1" class = "tab">
    blabalbal
</p>
<br>
<p class="title"><input type="image" src = "http://i.imgur.com/lZIalfM.png" onclick="return toggleMe('para2')" value="Toggle"> TEST</p><br>
<div id="para2">
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
</div>
<br>
<input type="image" src = "http://i.imgur.com/gitHhmZ.png" onclick="return toggleMe('para3')" value="Toggle"><br>
<span id="para3">
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
</span>
```

Comment: Please add a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) or jsbin (http://jsbin.com)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YqDhe/

Note that in JSFiddle the text appearing and disappearing does not work correctly but it does on the CMS I'm using.

Comment: `<input type="image">` isn’t really appropriate here. Just use `<img>`. Possibly wrapped in an `<a>` or a `<button>`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `return` in your `onclick` attribute.

```
<input type="image" src = "http://i.imgur.com/gitHhmZ.png" onclick="toggleMe('para3')" value="Toggle"><br>
```

You also need to assign your inputs to have IDs.

```
<input type="image" id="para3" src="http://i.imgur.com/gitHhmZ.png" onclick="toggleMe('para3')" value="Toggle"><br>
```